# How to setup static analyzers used in Magento's build pipeline?

Tags: github, submission

I'm a Magento code contributor who frequently encounters failing Static Test results in my Pull Requests on Github.  How do I integrate these static checks into my development environment so that I can check and fix these failures *before* I commit and push my changes?

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction

This document provides setup steps to get most static analyzers that are used in Magento's build
pipeline working locally in PHPStorm. This guide is written specifically for those using PHPStorm
on MacOS.

## Before You Begin

If you haven't already, make sure you have node and npm installed. Then, in Magento root
directory, run `npm install`. Ensure there is a `node_modules` directory in the root of your project
after installation before proceeding. For all of the static configuration changes below involving
the PHPStorm Preferences dialog, make sure you are clicking the "Apply" button before clicking
"OK" to close the Preferences dialog.

## JSCS

**Note: native JSCS support is deprecated in PHPStorm 2020.2; it must be installed via a plugin**
**Update Dec 1 2021: Magento does not use JSCS anymore**

1. Go to PHPStorm preferences > Other Settings > JSCS.
2. Check "Enable" if it is unchecked
3. Enter the path to your node binary (the result of outputting `which node` in your terminal).
4. Enter the path to your JSCS package: `[magento_root]/node_modules/jscs`
5. Specify a specific configuration path to the .jscsrc file: `[magento_root]dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Js/_files/jscs/.jscsrc`
6. To verify it works, in any JS file add `snake_case: [],` to any object literal and you should see
   warning about object key not being camel cased:
   [image: JSCS]

## ESLint

1. Go to PHPStorm preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint.
2. Click the "Manual ESLint configuration" radio button.
3. Fill in the adjacent input fields with the path to your node binary (the result of
   outputting `which node` in your terminal).
4. Enter the path to your ESLint package: `[magento_root]/node_modules/eslint`
5. Click the "Configuration File" radio button and in the adjacent input field enter the path to the
   ESLint file Magento uses, which is located
   in `[magento_root]/vendor/magento/magento-coding-standard/eslint/.eslintrc`.

To verify it works, in any JS file add /** Hello world */ as a doc comment to any method and you
should see a warning about the comment being on one line:

[image: ESLint]

## PHPCS

1. Go to PHPStorm preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Quality Tools >
   PHP_CodeSniffer.
2. Click the `...` button to bring up another configuration modal.
3. Enter the PHP_CodeSniffer path: `[magento_root]/vendor/bin/phpcs`

### Configuring PHPCS for Magento Coding Standard

1. Go to the [Magento Coding Standard GitHub Repository](https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard)
2. Follow instructions within the README to install the Magento Coding Standard for PHPCS.
   Verify it's installed with `vendor/bin/phpcs -i`. You should see `Magento2` in the output.
3. Go to PHPStorm preferences > Editor > Inspections, and in the adjacent window go to > PHP > Quality Tools > PHP_CodeSniffer validation.
4. Under Coding Standard dropdown, select Magento2.

See the image below for example configuration:

[image: PHPCS Configuration]

To verify it works, add the following PHP snippet: `$base = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);`. It should give you a warning about use
of basename and use of superglobals being forbidden.

[image: PHPCS]

## PHPMD

1. Go to PHPStorm preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Quality Tools > Mess
   Detector.
2. Click the ... button to bring up another configuration modal.
3. Enter the PHP Mess Detector path: `[magento_root]/vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd`
4. Go to PHPStorm preferences > Editor > Inspections, and in the adjacent window go to > PHP > Quality Tools > PHP Mess Detector validation.
5. Under custom rulesets, add the path to the PHPMD ruleset Magento
   uses: `[magento_root]/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/_files/phpmd/rule set.xml`

See the image below for example configuration:
[image: PHPMD Configuration]

To verify it works, add an unused private method to a class and you should see a warning from
PHPMD about it not being used.

[image: PHPMD]